# Start an Activity in full cycle with out showing UI

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have activityB with UI which is working fine as a regular activity with showing UI upon calling from another activityA. Now, I want to call activityB and let the activity complete the entire activity cycle without showing its UI.

So far I had tried:

1. Set theme in Manifest:
   android:theme = "@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

But the problem is I need to setContentView() in ActivityB so that UI element can be recognized in the ActivityB. This ran into error.

2. Put finish() in activityB onCreate()
   The activityB did not complete the full activity cycle. It end at finish().

Any thought about how I can achieve starting an Activity in full cycle without showing its UI.

Thank you

Comment: can you tell us why you are in need of this behaviour ? There might be other way to do . If it is just a matter of visibilty, you can hide all views untill you are ready to show it back, but does not seems right way to achieve anything that I can think of .

Comment: @Jimmy, ActivityB is working fine with showing UI. I want to retain this feature and also want to try if I can reuse the ActivityB running as background service. I think It will be easy to separate them into 2 separate Activity, one with UI and another one without UI. Thanks for your idea.

Comment: Not sure If I got you. Just want to make you aware that if you are running long process in UI thread ( I think it is 5 sec ), android will try to kill it thinking it is inactive / not responding. For that , you probably want runt your process in separate thread OR service thread  or use async task.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you pass some boolean through intent if UI should be shown or not:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    boolean isShowUI = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_IS_SHOW_UI, true);

    if (isShowUI) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
    }

    //your onCreate logic
}
```